# Sorting by the newest comment with 3 tables users,posts, and comments in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[image: My code]

I'm sorting my post by the newest comment timestamp. It works but when it comes to paginating the posts I get empty paginated posts in my rendered pagination.

Comment: Do not add screenshot of code. Copy your code and paste in your question as code block.

Comment: What does "empty posts" mean? What database are you using? It looks like you also tried `groupBy('id')` instead of `distinct('id')`: What was the result?

Answer (score -2):

Sorry about my previous reply but do check this on laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins > sub-query joins or 
try: ->orderBy('comments.created_at','desc'), instead of using the orderByRaw(), if also you want to orderBy multiple columns you can chain the other column to the previous like this 
->orderBy('comments.created_at','desc')
->orderBy('confession.created_at','desc') 
also had similar problem some days back and that was how i fixed mine. hope its helps.

Comment: I need to sort the post with the latest comment and then the latest post.

Comment: latest post or confessions?

Comment: because there is no post table from your screenshot only a confession table,comment and user